# No 'Instance Features' in installation setup of Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to install SQL Server 2012 Express on my personal computer (fresh install of Win 8). I downloaded the installation files on the Microsoft Website. The filename is SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe (about 614 Mb).

When running this file, I got the 'Feature Selection' Screen (see below).

[image]

As you can see there is nothing in 'Instance Features' section. It seems to be anormal. When finishing the setup, there is no errors reported. After restarting my computer, I execute the Management Studio and see that there is no Sql Server instance available.

Do I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded the wrong file. SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe is just SQL Management Studio.

You want one of the ones that start with SQLEXPR from this page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Ough Thank you. I started downloading the right file. I'll keep you in touch.